# Show that the game has a unique Nash equilibrium (in pure or mixed strategies)

Tags: self-learning, game-theory, nash-equilibrium

Each of 15 students simultaneously announces a number in the set {1, 2, . . . , 100}. A prize of 1 TL is split equally between all students whose number is closest to 1/3 of the class average. Show that the game has a unique Nash equilibrium (in pure or mixed strategies).

My answer

I Compute the sequence of sets of pure strategies defining the process of iterated elimination of strictly dominated strategies for every student i.

And I found that (1,1,...,1) is Nash equilibrium. But I cannot prove its uniqueness and show this in a formal way.

Comment: If I see that the average guess of my fellow students is $N$ then I want to guess something less than $N$.  Thus there is steady downward pressure on everyone's guesses until it is impossible to guess any lower.

Comment: This is a famous question in game theory. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guess_2/3_of_the_average#:~:text=In%20game%20theory%2C%20%22guess%202,to%20the%2023%20average.